# Is there a way to name Link attachments in Trello?

Tags: trello

When I attach a few links to a card, it's not always easy to tell them apart. (I have to do so by reading the part of the url that's visible). It'd be great if I could name the link so it's more readable.

You can do this with links you embed in the description using their Markup. For example:

```
Click [here](http://www.whatever.com) to go to the page.
```

Is there a way to do this with link attachments?

Comment: Mmh as far as I know there is not, however a URL shortner may make jt a little easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can only do this on the web or desktop apps, though. If you click on the attachment button, a popup will appear asking for you to paste the link. It will also have a bar asking if you want to put a title.